# connecting to remote database using spoon over network

Tags: mysql, oracle, pentaho, etl

I have a job which has source connection as oracle on windows.

On Destination it should update a mysql database table on ubuntu linux server over ssh.

Is this possible to do?

In insert/update step is it possible to give connection type over ssh?

In need of help.

Comment: When you say 'ssh' do you mean that you use port forwarding?

Comment: yeah,port forwarding

Comment: Have you configured the local port of the forwarding in your insert/update component? For debugging: can you connect to your remote DB using a shell client?

Comment: I have not tried that..

Answer (score 0):

Target insert/update step works through JDBC connection. Therefore you need to open port on MySQL DB to be able to connect to DB.

Comment: by default, MySQL installation doesn't bind the port (default is 3306) to anything listening to external connections. It only accepts local connections. You need to change your MySQL configurations to accept external connections (see bind-address on my.cnf file)

Answer (score 0):

You can open a connection via Putty and use 127.0.0.1 in the jdbc connector to connect to your DB via the tunnel opened by your putty session.